# Create a stacked bar chart with already grouped data using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that has grouped values like this:
[image]

How can I turn it into a stacked bar chart using ggplot? Thanks

Comment: I’m guessing that downvote is for using an image when text is requested for data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example That's the link we're supposed to post in those cases? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

dt <- data.table(Type =  c('a',  'b', 'c', 'd', 'E'),
                 Location1 = c(0, 3, 44, 5, 8),
                 Location2 = c(2, 26, 33, 2, 0),
                 Location3 = c(23, 6, 6, 8, 0),
                 Location4 = c(32, 22, 89, 0, 0))

dt <- melt(dt, id.vars = c("Type"))

ggplot(dt, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: stackbar]